# We are currently experiencing service disruptions and are unable to provide quota information at this time

Tags: oauth

I am going get an API key, but before that it needed me to verify an Oauth consent screen, but the information shown is kinda strange. I wanna know what's happening

Comment: it's also showed that Verification Status is: verification not required

Comment: can you please share your code/error message?